# With AutoMapper how does one get a value from a mapped parent to a child collection member without using AfterMap?

Tags: c#, automapper

Assume the following:

```
public class ParentSource
{
    public Guid parentId { get; set; }

    public ICollection<ChildSource> children { get; set; }
}

public class ChildSource
{
    public Guid childId { get; set; }
}

public class ParentDestination
{
    public Guid parentId { get; set; }

    public ICollection<ChildDestination> children { get; set; }
}

public class ChildDestination
{
    public Guid childId { get; set; }
    public Guid parentId { get; set; }
    public ParentDestination parent;
}
```

How does one populate the ChildDestination object with the parent's information using AutoMapper without using `.AfterMap`?

Comment: What's wrong with using AfterMap?

Comment: Most probably nothing. I think the entity framework error I was getting that prompted the question was, after all, unrelated. But I remain curious if it's at all possible. In fact it might be through the map configuration options in .ForMember().

Comment: Not available through the IMemberConfigurationOptions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the only way to populate a child object in a collection with a reference to parent instance of the member collection without using `.AfterMap()` is with a custom `TypeConverter<TSource, TDestination>`.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<ParentSource, ParentDestination>().ConvertUsing<CustomTypeConverter>();

        ParentSource ps = new ParentSource() { parentId = Guid.NewGuid() };
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            ps.children.Add(new ChildSource() { childId = Guid.NewGuid() });
        }

        var mappedObject = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<ParentDestination>(ps);

    }
}

public class ParentSource
{
    public ParentSource()
    {
        children = new HashSet<ChildSource>();
    }

    public Guid parentId { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ChildSource> children { get; set; }
}

public class ChildSource
{
    public Guid childId { get; set; }
}

public class ParentDestination
{
    public ParentDestination()
    {
        children = new HashSet<ChildDestination>();
    }
    public Guid parentId { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ChildDestination> children { get; set; }
}

public class ChildDestination
{
    public Guid childId { get; set; }
    public Guid parentId { get; set; }
    public ParentDestination parent { get; set; }
}

public class CustomTypeConverter : AutoMapper.TypeConverter<ParentSource, ParentDestination>
{
    protected override ParentDestination ConvertCore(ParentSource source)
    {
        var result = new ParentDestination() { parentId = source.parentId };
        result.children = source.children.Select(c => new ChildDestination() { childId = c.childId, parentId = source.parentId, parent = result }).ToList();
        return result;
    }
}
```

Or you could use `.AfterMap()`. :)

Answer (score 1):

As you said in your comment, the ForMember would be another option if you don't want to use AfterMap.  You could create a ForMember converter that, using linq, could pretty quickly loop through the source children, convert them to destination children and then set the Parent property.

Or you could use AfterMap.  :)

**UPDATE:**

Maybe something like this (untested):

```
.ForMember(d => d.children, 
    o => o.MapFrom(s => 
        from child in s.children
        select new ChildDestination {
            childId = child.childId,
            parentId = s.parentId,
            parent = s
        }));
```

Comment: ok, but if one were to take the .ForMember() approach, how do you access the collection's source member's parent?

Comment: Almost, the setting of the parent to s is not correct. The parent on the ChildDestination is an instance of the ParentDestination object. If you implement a Mapper.Map statement there to "coerce" instance s, I think you actually begin a weird recursion which doesn't actually reference the ParentDestination instance, which still only creates newly mapped instances.

Comment: What was that you said? "Or you could use AfterMap. :)" Or you could use a custom TypeConverter.